# webpack-dev-server hot reloading does not work on the case that use vim edit files

Tags: vim, webpack, webpack-dev-server

when I use vim editor like `vim xx.js`

and `:w` or `:wq` or `:w!` save the file.

the webpack-dev-server HRM does not notice that.

and even I reloaded page manually that's not ok.

Comment: Did you reload the page in your browser, *bypassing cache* or even clearing the cache first?

Answer (score 3):

Try configuring `set backupcopy=yes` in your `.vimrc`.

Comment: Discussion about this here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/781

Answer (score 0):

You sure you setup the entry point correctly ?

It is more like your `webpack config` issue instead of `vim` issue.

This is the following items you may want to check

1) Make sure you set up your entry point correctly, for example,

```
entry = [
    "webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080",
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './'+APP_ENTRY_POINT
];
```

2) Make sure you have the right loaders config, might be your config is looking at `jsx` instead of `js` ?